# Increment DateTime Column Based on Alphabetical Sort of Another Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server 2019.

I have a table with a varchar Name field and a datetime Created field.  I need to incrementally update the Created datetime based on an alphabetic sort of the Name field.  E.g. Name value A would be now and Name value Z would be x seconds later.

There's a question here for the same issue but it is MySQL and the answer doesn't work with SQL Server.

Sample table:

```
Id    Name    Created
1     FMI     2023-03-01 12:01:16
2     MMT     2023-03-22 15:45:31
3     TPH     2023-08-10 10:10:19
4     TPA     2023-08-10 10:12:01
5     SMA     2023-09-07 09:51:13
6     NUA     2023-09-13 17:11:05
```

Output I'm looking for:

```
Id    Name    Created
1     FMI     2024-02-06 15:14:42
2     MMT     2024-02-06 15:14:43
6     NUA     2024-02-06 15:14:44
5     SMA     2024-02-06 15:14:45
4     TPA     2024-02-06 15:14:46
3     TPH     2024-02-06 15:14:47
```

Comment: It shouldn't be hard to translate a MySQL solution to SQL Server - give it a go and ask about what you get stuck on.

Comment: Should be just a simple `row_number()` + `dateadd()`.

Comment: Please post what you have tried and your one challenge with it so we may help you fix it.  This does somewhat conflict with what we would normally see for a column named "Created"

Comment: To be clear: it looks like this ignores the original `Created` column completely, and bases the result entirely on the current timestamp.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH SortedRows AS (
    SELECT Id, Name, CreateDate,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Name) AS RowNumber
    FROM temp
)
UPDATE temp
SET temp.CreateDate = DATEADD(SECOND, SortedRows.RowNumber, GETDATE())
FROM temp
INNER JOIN SortedRows ON temp.Id = SortedRows.Id;

SELECT Id, Name, CreateDate
FROM temp
ORDER BY Name;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/8sA0HqkZ

Comment: It's not clear they want to change the original table. Sounds to me more like just selecting the new data.

Comment: I think you are right. Edited my response Thank you.

https://dbfiddle.uk/8sA0HqkZ

Comment: You don't need to rejoin, you can update `SortedRows` directly. https://dbfiddle.uk/TVUAM8mT

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely certain I've understood the question properly, but if I have you want this:

```
SELECT Id, Name,
    DATEADD(second, row_number() over (order by Name), current_timestamp) Created
FROM [MyTable]
ORDER BY Name
```